# Can you view a gif icon as an still thumbnail image?

Tags: command-line, icons, convert, thumbnails

I have a few GIF images, but they are just a grey icon that says GIF. Can't tell them apart otherwise aside from the name.

In other words: my picture folder has images, you know which one you are selecting based on an icon that has its image as the icon. Gifs are just grey icons... all the same.

Is there a program or command that can convert GIF icons to stills of the gif?  Like image icons?  I'm looking for a program to do it automatically the way it should be.

Comment: I believe you meant there are only blank grey thumbnails for gif files in file manager. It works fine here. What's your Ubuntu version?